# Where can I download the built in Unlock.ogg and Lock.ogg sound files for Android?

Tags: android, audio

Also what is the best place to get free sound effect files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/system/media/audio/ui had nothing. I ended up browsing a bunch of not so great sound effect sites til I found something acceptable. Didnt find any sites which were really satifactory though.

Answer (score 0):

/system/media/audio/ui

Apparently the answer of 22 characters isn't acceptable, I need to enter 30 characters so I'll ramble on a bit...

Comment: The emulators only have camera_click.ogg and VideoRecord.ogg. Plus my phone is not rooted so I'm not sure if I can access all the ogg files. Is there an online link somewhere?